# How to monitor read & write speed to specific device or mount point

Tags: hard-disk, performance, devices, monitoring

How can I monitor the read & write speed to a specific device or mount point in Linux, for example `/dev/sdc2` which is mounted to `/mnt/data/`?

Would like to display the speed in MB/s for example and update once or twice a second.

Answer (score 1):

`iostat` is your source of truth, in particular `iostat -md /dev/devicename 1` for your use case.

`-m     Display statistics in megabytes per second.`

`-z     Tell iostat to omit output for any devices for which there was no activity during the sample period.`

```
root@kahnbox:/home/kahn$ iostat -md /dev/sda 1
Linux 5.4.17-100.fc30.x86_64 (kahnbox)  31/07/20        _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

Device             tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda               4.61         0.00         0.12       2521     152976

Device             tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda               3.00         0.00         0.04          0          0

Device             tps    MB_read/s    MB_wrtn/s    MB_read    MB_wrtn
sda               0.00         0.00         0.00          0          0
```

`tps: Indicate the number of transfers per second that were issued to the device. A transfer is an I/O request to the device. Multiple logical requests can be combined into a single I/O request to the device. A transfer is of indeterminate size.`

I prefer `-z` flag as it will cut down on chatter. With an inclusion of `1` at the end of the command, you'll be getting results every second so long as they can be provided.

If you wish to install this utility, you'll need to grab the `sysstat` package:

```
root@kahnbox:/home/kahn$ yum whatprovides iostat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Last metadata expiration check: 1:32:20 ago on Fri 31 Jul 2020 13:44:22 EDT.
sysstat-11.7.3-3.fc30.x86_64 : Collection of performance monitoring tools for Linux
Repo        : @System
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/iostat

sysstat-11.7.3-3.fc30.x86_64 : Collection of performance monitoring tools for Linux
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/iostat
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `iostat` is a tool of choice for this purposes. Example:

```bsh
iostat -d -t -p sdc 1 2
```

This command print information about speed of `sdc` two times with interval equals 1 second.

Comment: This command given the output and exits, plus speed is displayed in kB not mB.

Comment: @Smeterlink you can use `m` option `iostat -m`